# ZTest result not making sense

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I'm using version 10.

I'm having difficulty with understanding why I'm getting some output from the ZTest function. Here is the code for my specific example.

```
In[1]:= data = {553.`, 552.`, 567.`, 579.`, 550.`, 541.`, 537.`, 553.`, 552.`, 546.`, 538.`, 553.`, 581.`, 539.`, 529.`};

In[2]:= ZTest[data, 20, 540, "TestStatistic"]

Out[2]= 9.81495
```

Now, I write my own z statistic calculation based on the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score).

$$Z = \frac{\bar{X}-\operatorname{E}[X]}{\sigma(X)/\sqrt{n}}.$$

```
In[3]:= myZTest[data_List, s_, m_] := (Mean[data] - m)/(s/Sqrt[Length[data]])

In[4]:= myZTest[data, 20, 540]

Out[4]:= 2.19469
```

My understanding of how ZTest works is that `Out[2]==Out[4]`, what gives?  Do I misunderstand the definition?

Edit:

I've checked my example with the wolfram alpha z test calculator and the result agrees with Out[4].

Comment: Square the variance argument...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to square your argument:

```
ZTest[data, 20^2, 540., "TestStatistic"]

(* 2.19469 *)
```